# I can't use anaconda to install packages

Tags: anaconda

I can't use anaconda to install packages, It will return `404` error.
I have added some channels such as "https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/free/", It doesn't work.

anaconda shows:

> Collecting package metadata: failed
>
> UnavailableInvalidChannel: The channel is not accessible or is
>   invalid.   channel name: anaconda/pkgs/main   channel url:
>   https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/main   error code:
>   404
>
> You will need to adjust your conda configuration to proceed. Use
>   `conda config --show channels` to view your configuration's current
>   state, and use `conda config --show-sources` to view config file
>   locations.

Comment: Try to install Anaconda3-4.4.0-Windows-x86_64 or Anaconda3-4.4.0-Linux-x86_64.sh which was released in 2017-05-26, it has Python 3.6. Good Luck..

Comment: With Python 3.6 you will can work with  matplotlib, tensorflow, pandas, keras, sklearn etc.